# What would a sotapanna do?

Tags: theravada, five-precepts

There are many arguments whether a sotapanna has a perfect morality/sila or not. But let's base this topic on this Sutta:

> With what four factors of a stream enterer is he endowed?
>
> ...Is endowed with virtues that are not broken, not defective, not
>   spotted, consistent, not blemished, not enslaved, praised by the wise
>   as conducive to concentration and desired by the noble ones He is
>   endowed with these four factors of a stream enterer....[Anguttara Nikaya 9.27](http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/4Anguttara-Nikaya/Anguttara6/09-navakanipata/003-sattavasavaggo-e.html)

Now, for example, a deadly worm is in the stomach of a sotapanna's child. The only thing to help his child is to kill the worm otherwise his child will die. With his perfect morality, what would a sotapanna do, will a sotapanna (naturally) let his child die?

Comment: He would take the kid to a doctor.

Comment: See also [Trolley problem and its variants in Buddhist ethics](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/12237/254) -- what makes this question different is that one of the "people" in the question is a deadly worm instead.

Comment: See also [Are buddhist allowed to kill mosquitoes](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/7820/4231)

Comment: I am sorry I can't answer in this topic for you. However, I put it into the blog at this link. This answer can destroy your doubt. There was similar case in commentary which I think you will interest to read: http://unmixedtheravada.blogspot.com/2018/01/profit-managementbodhisattaselfsatta.html

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that a Sotapan would look into alternative removal of the worm but eventually probably get rid of it one way or another.

Answer (score -3):

Without hesitation, kill the worm.

The sotapanna has overcome attachment to moral precepts and rules (sīlabbata-parāmāsa) and is therefore guided by the conscience developed in the heart.

> *Now, a trifling evil act done by what sort of individual is experienced in the here & now, and for the most part barely appears
>   for a moment? There is the case where a certain individual is
>   developed in the body, developed in virtue, developed in mind
>   [i.e., painful feelings cannot invade the mind and stay there],
>   developed in discernment: unrestricted, large-hearted, dwelling with
>   the immeasurable. A trifling evil act done by this sort of individual
>   is experienced in the here & now, and for the most part barely appears
>   for a moment.*
>
> *Lonaphala Sutta: The Salt Crystal*